# How to handle end of turn in a card game

Tags: socket.io

I'm building a simple card game to learn node.js and socket.io. When all players toss their cards at the end of the turn, I could automatically clear the table and set the next turn, but if I do it as soon as the last card is thrown, it gets a little awkward as other players do not see what the last player played.

Currently, I see two options:

1. ask each player to click "continue" before clearing the table OR
2. introduce a delay and then clear the table automatically. I'm not sure how long should this delay be?

Is there some better way to to this?

Comment: Make it an explicit state. for example: a state that is only reached after all the players have passed, and/or have no more cards (depending on the game: in poker you can still raise even at the end of the game.) Game-design==dialog-design.

Comment: Logically it already is an explicit state. I'm just looking for friendly UI to represent it and I'm considering whether to move to subsequent state (clean table) automatically.

Comment: Well, it depends on the nature/rules of the particular game. In some games, it can be made implicit (no cards left to play, everyone has passed) In some it should not (you can raise bets after the last card has been played/revealed. So you need different state machines for different types of games. In some cases, "automagic" is *not* user friendly (people may want to take a last look at the cards on the table before reshuffling), in some it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I set the 4 seconds delay before clearing the table. If some of the players plays a new card (new round started) I "overwrite" that card spot but keep the old cards on the table until delay is over.